# Calculate % discount of price. Javascript

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

Trying to build a Javascript %age Discount calculator for my webshop. The problem is that the calculator calculates some products wrong by 2-10%. Please help, whats wrong in the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

/*
Least allowed discount to show.
*/
var minDiscount = 15;



$('.gridArticlePrices').each(function() {
    /* Get ordinary price */
    var oldPrice = $(this).children('.gridArticlePriceRegular').html();
    /* Get sale price */
    var newPrice = $(this).children('.gridArticlePrice').children('.reducedPrice').html();

    if ((oldPrice) && (newPrice)) {
        /* Convert to numbers instead of strings */
        var oldPrice = parseInt(oldPrice.replace("/[^0-9]/g", ""));
        var newPrice = parseInt(newPrice.replace("/[^0-9]/g", ""));

        /* Calcuate the precentage, rounded of to 0 decimals */
        var discount = Math.round(100 - ((newPrice / oldPrice) * 100));

        /* If the precentage is higher than "var min Discount" then write out the discount next to the products price.*/
        if (discount >= minDiscount) {
            $(this).parent().after("<div class='discount'>-" + discount + "%</div>");
        }
    }
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Well for one thing you're using `parseInt()`, which will ignore any fractional part.  It's for **integers**, and presumably some of your prices are `$2.99` or whatever.

Comment: can you add this code in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bar9v/

As you can see, some of the red discount labels calculating wrong.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

My original suggestion to use parseFloat was assuming your prices included decimal components. As I see now, they are in fact integers, so parseInt works fine.

The actual issue is your replace() call isn't removing anything. You should remove the quotes around the regex, and then it will remove the extra characters you don't want.

```
var oldPrice = parseInt(oldPrice.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
var newPrice = parseInt(newPrice.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
```

Note: If you do need to handle decimal prices, you would need to add "." to you regex (so it doesn't get removed), and use parseFloat instead of parseInt.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for quick reply. I tried that, but i keep on getting the same results. 
Check out my JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Bar9v/